# Java 7u45 Security Warning: Allow access to the following application from this web site?

Tags: java, security, warnings

How can I cancel following warning?

Allow access to the following application from this web site?:

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkl3k.jpg

Comment: Documentation on ths topic can be found in: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/liveconnect_changes_in_7u45 and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u45-relnotes-2016950.html - It might be also worth reading the announcements for the next scheduled update Java 7u51: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias

Comment: I saw it. But It's not working..I could not.

Comment: please provide more details what you did and what happened. And what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I also spent few days finding a solution for this problem as well.
And finally today hoping that this resolves our problem as we are still waiting for our applets to be signed by our client.

For our case the solution that works based on our internal testing is to remove the Trusted-Library attribute from MANIFEST.

You may follow this link

[JAR File Manifest Attributes for Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/manifest.html#permissions)

Comment: It worked, after amending the manifest and re-signed the jar files it does not prompt for security warning anymore for JREu45. The only problem is if your user is using previous JRE update or version then the security warning will prompt again as there is a conflict between the Trusted-Library and the Caller-Allowable-Codebase attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are facing is [described here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/liveconnect_changes_in_7u45). The solution, assuming that you are serving the applet from a known location, is to specify the [Caller-Allowable-Codebase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/manifest.html#caller_allowable) attribute in your manifest.

According to the documentation, if you are not doing live connect from a known location, then you should be able to specify `Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *`.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer you can not let this warning to not appear because of security reasons.
j7u51 prediction 
[image: Check this screenshot taken from a PC running on j7u45]

Comment: you can not force the application not to display alert dialog, because whatever you do this dialog will still appear. But as a user you can check `allow always` and not let the dialog appear to prompt you next time

Comment: Okey. But I couldn't find such as option. How can I do that?

Comment: Depends on browsers and since the last java update j7u45. the remember choice field has been removed and for the update j7u51 Java will **NOT ALLOW** to run application/applets from **UNKNOWN SOURCES**. refer the edit.